# Views Json Source data Cached

Tags: 8, views

I'm using the [Views Json Source](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_json_source) module to load information from a Views Rest Export page on an other website into another website.

But for some reason the view is stuck with old information. I'm pulling in a calendar from the source site. But even though the data from the source site is changing the data in the other site is not.

To solve this I disabled cache for both views but without success When clearing cache on the source site and then the other site the data is changed.

What can I do to make the view look at the rest export on every load of the block?

Comment: Have you tried looking directly at the JSON from the source site, ie have you confirmed that the JSON is actually changing (I think you are saying it does, but it wasn't 100% clear)? If so then yes definitely, an issue with the destination site. If it's not changing, try adding a parameter to the url to see if that changes the source json.

If you have confirmed that the JSON is changing, it does seem like a cache issue. the module definitely does some caching,
You could look for it in the cache table? views_json_source_
Check the dblog for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I uninstalled the module and created my own javascript function. Here I had the same problem. Making me realize the problem was caching in some form. The answer to the question was simply adding a query of the current date to the url.

For more informatie: [Views rest export does not update](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/302453/views-rest-export-does-not-update)